# Cambios en php.ini no modifican el valor

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo un proyecto que se realizó con las etiquetas cortas de php:

```
<? ?>
```

cuando intento modificar el valor de "short_open_tags" del php.ini, no modifica el mismo cuando reviso en el archivo info.php.

Me fijé que la ruta del ini sea la correcta de acuerdo a la misma pantalla de información de PHP,  también me fije si otros .ini están sobreescribiendo los valores, pero no.

En el archivo .htaccess del proyecto agregué también la directiva php_value short_open_tags On y no lo modifica.

Después de cada cambio reinicio apache, pero no hay ningun efecto.

¿Como puedo hacer que quede modificado?

Comment: Debes tener en consideración que probablemente encuentres mínimo 2 archivos `php.ini`, uno para la **CLI** y otro para **Apache**, si estás ejecutando el script desde la CLI, modifica este. Además reinicia **Apache** y **PHP** luego del cambio

Comment: Si estás en un entorno Linux, usualmente hay un servicio fastCGI que mantiene la config de PHP ([FPM](https://www.php.net/manual/es/install.fpm.php)), así que además de reiniciar apache, también [reiniciar el servicio](https://www.google.com/search?q=restart+php-fpm) php-fpm.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos, tenia que reiniciar el servicio php-fpm